# Can I filter/query a replicated map in hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

Can i filter my replicated map with predicates like IMap?

example:

```
replicatedMap.values(Predicates.equal("id", "123"))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ReplicatedMap doesn't provide an API for using Predicates.
One alternative is to make use of the below API but again, it would be our responsibility to implement the Comparator ourselves.

```
ReplicatedMap::values(Comparator<V> comparator);
```

Comment: I saw it, but comparator don't soves my problems. There is a reason for replicatedmap  does not implement it? Thanks for your answer.